# IS Android N and newer ignores the v1 signature?

Tags: android, apk, schema, signature, signing

Is Android N and newer ignores the v1 signature If we signed apk with v1 v2 and v3 schema. If we have all 3 schemas so s there any security risk in having the v1 signature in the app?

Comment: [The documentation](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning#v1) mentions some of the drawbacks of verifying v1 signatures: _"The APK verifier needs to process lots of untrusted (not yet verified) data structures and then discard data not covered by the signatures. This offers a sizeable attack surface. Moreover, the APK verifier must uncompress all compressed entries, consuming more time and memory."_

Comment: That is v1 scheme knowledge , what if we sign v1 and v2 so N and newer will ignore the v1 untrusted (not yet verified) data structures.?  my question is very simple .

Comment: Your question currently reads as : what would the drawback be if Android also verified the v1 signature in addition to newer signatures? And that's what I commented on. If you meant something else then please edit your question and clarify exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure updated.  i just want to know that if my apk is signed with v1 v2 and v3 then N and newer version is ignore V1 ??

Comment: The logic for that is described in the flow chart (Figure 1) on the page I linked to in my first comment, and also [on the signature v2 documentation page](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2#verification).